# w word regular expression headache

Tags: regex

I have been having some fun with a regular expression insofar as the \w expression will not work for me.   When I use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]*[\.][a-zA-Z0-9.]*$/.test(x);
```

everything is working weel, but when i use this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@\w*[\.][a-zA-Z0-9.]*$/.test(x);
```

or this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]*@\w+[\.][a-zA-Z0-9.]*$/.test(x);
```

no dice.

Any mention of \w anywhere in the expression and I get a false return whatever the pattern match.  E.g. /^\w+@\w+$/

I can solve the problem using the square brackets and the a-z etc. just about, but i am just curious to know what is going on here for future reference and personal sanity really.

Thx,

Comment: Please provide a sample string that the first regex works and the second/third fail on.

Comment: In fact i've just taken this to its extreme and I get a false trying to match 'abc' with /^\w+$/ or /^(\w+)*$/ or pretty much anything else, so there is something deeper at play here.  Has \w been deprecated or something? or am i just getting this whole thing completely wrong?? thx.

Comment: There are many flavors of regular expressions, so maybe yours doesn't support `\w`.

Comment: OK thanks TIm - give me a sec please, i will just do it again with the debugger.

Comment: mm@mm.com  this works for the first not the second or third or anything with [a-z etc.] replaced wtih \w+

Comment: Thx Golez - how should i check for the allowable characterset for valid email address if i have not got \w on my regex pls.  [a-zA-Z0-9.-_] perhaps, but this is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub-pattern:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]
```

is not only faulty (due to unescaped hyphen in the middle) it is NOT equivalent of `\w` which is same as: `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Instead of `\w` use:

```
[\w.-]
```

instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]`

An **unescaped** `-` in the middle of character class acts as **range** rather than literal hyphen.

**Complete regex:**

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[\w.-]+[\.][a-zA-Z0-9.]+$/
```

Answer (score 2):

`[.-_]` matches `.`, `/`, `0`, `1`, ...., `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` (everything between `.` and `_`).

So, it matches more than what `\w` matches.